# como imprimir los elementos que están dentro de un ciclo en python?

Tags: array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: al imprimir las notas de los estudiantes solo me imprime la nota del ultimo estudiante ingresado]
al imprimir las notas de los estudiantes solo me imprime la nota del ultimo estudiante ingresado

Comment: Te muestra la ultima porque dentro de la funcion leer_datos() justamente eso hace al final con el print("la nota del estudiante", n, "es", s), si quieres que te lo muestre cada vez que registren una nota, debes mover esa linea para adentro del for. O si quieres que te imprima todas al final, entonces debes iterar con un for la lista "a" que defines al principio.

Answer (score 0):

Concuerdo con la persona que ya te comento, te esta imprimiendo solo el ultimo porque son los ultimos datos que estan entrando a tu variable, si quieres que te muestre cada estudiante ingresado lo que tienes que hacer es mover tu linea `print("la nota del estudiante", n, "es", s)` dentro del for, para que te lo vaya mostrando cada vez que entra al ciclo.